# How to add and use multiple actions into Apigilities RPC Generated Controller

Tags: php, api, zend-framework2, rpc, laminas-api-tools

i need your advice. 
I need to create multiple Actions in RPC style API Controller generated by Apigility. 
How do I need to make routing, to make it work like it is in normal zend application.

```
'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',/*I need flexible route like this one*/
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Code generated by Apigility is:

```
<?php
namespace TestAPI\V1\Rpc\Test;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class TestController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function TestAction()
    {
        /*Added by myself*/
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'id' => 'test',
        ));
    }

}
```

and routing is generated this way:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\TestControllerFactory',
    ),
),
'zf-rpc' => array(
    'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => array(
        'service_name' => 'test',
        'http_methods' => array(
            0 => 'GET',
        ),
        'route_name' => 'test-api.rpc.test',
    ),
),
```

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Multiple actions per controller is discouraged by Matthew Weier O'Phinney (Apigility's creator):

> No.
>
> Apigility's RPC functionality posits one route -> one controller -> 
>   one action (although we allow multiple HTTP methods to it). This is 
>   for several reasons:
>
> - Simplifies configuration
> - Simplifies finding the code for a given route (exactly one place to look)
> - Helps prevent large controllers
>
> What I'd do is create a service object that can handle the various 
>   related operations, and then an RPC service per discrete operation 
>   (unless that operation could be described using different HTTP verbs 
>   on the same route, that is). Then inject each controller with that 
>   service object, and call the appropriate method.

source: https://groups.google.com/a/zend.com/d/msg/apigility-users/Or3xBLAd9Y0/RzQKIMpaV0cJ

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

Try register aliases on controllers key to your controller and register each alias on zf-rpc config.

Something like that:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\TestControllerFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test2\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller',
        'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test3\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller',
    ),
),


'zf-rpc' => array(
    'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => array(
        'service_name' => 'test',
        'http_methods' => array(
            0 => 'GET',
        ),
        'route_name' => 'test-api.rpc.test',
    ),
    'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test2\\Controller' => array(
        'service_name' => 'test2',
        'http_methods' => array(
            0 => 'GET',
        ),
        'route_name' => 'test-api.rpc.test2',
    ),
    'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test3\\Controller' => array(
        'service_name' => 'test3',
        'http_methods' => array(
            0 => 'GET',
        ),
        'route_name' => 'test-api.rpc.test3',
    ),
),
```

Probably you have to copy and change de route config and another configs.

Solution 2

You can try generate another rpc service and change the factory to a alias, all configs will generate to you.

after you generate the service, you will get something like this:

```
'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\TestControllerFactory',
            'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test2\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test2\\TestControllerFactory',
        ),
    ),
```

You have to change to something like this:

```
'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\TestControllerFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test2\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller',
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for routing :

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => 'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\TestControllerFactory',
    ),
),
'zf-rpc' => array(
    'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller' => array(
        'service_name' => 'test',
        'http_methods' => array(
            0 => 'GET',
        ),
        'route_name' => 'test-api.rpc.test',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'test-api.rpc.test' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/api/test[/:action_name]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' =>'TestAPI\\V1\\Rpc\\Test\\Controller',
                        'action' => 'test',
                ),
            ),
        ),))
```

`
And in your controller :

```
<?php
namespace TestAPI\V1\Rpc\Test;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class TestController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        $action_name = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action_name');
        switch ($action_name) {
            case 'test1':
                return $this->test1Action();
            default:
                return array();
        }
    }

    public function test1Action(){
        //Your code here
        return ...; //preferable to be array
    }
}
```

the url is .../api/test/test1

I Hope this will help you.